# Fit image to margins InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got an InDesign document with multiple A4 pages, with a 12.7 mm margin on all sides. I've got a bunch of images I want to drop onto each page.

To save me dropping in each image and manually resizing it to fit between the width or height of the margins is there a "fit to margins" option in InDesign.

I've made a video to better articulate my question here : https://streamable.com/es4z9

Comment: @Danielillo , i actually started editting that other question, but on review that questions was related to getting the image to fit its own frame, rather than between the margins, hence i created this new question.

Comment: Create an image frame from margin to margin at the master page and follow the dup question's answer